# Alias a command with the Incoming Prompt Options

Tags: openconnect

I have an alias in my `.zshrc` which connects me to my VPN.
The alias is like this:

```bsh
alias vvv="sudo openconnect xx.xx.xxx.xx"
```

After running this command, I will be asked a `yes/no` question, after typing `yes`, I have to copy one of the recommended groups, then I will be asked to enter my `username` and then `password`.

Is there any way to accommodate those prompt options into my alias all in one place? Note that, this is different from passing argument options to an alias command, those options will be displayed after entering the command.

Comment: What is asking you these questions: the `openconnect` command, or some prompt from a server? Do you want to send more input to the `openconnect` command (or whatever remote entity it's feeding input to) after these initial questions?

Comment: I want my alias to be something like this: `vvv` and the alias value be something like `sudo openconnect xx.xx.xxx.xx --yes recommended-group username=something&password=password`. I do not want to enter those later commands by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Update your alias to something like below:

```
alias vvv='sudo openconnect serverAddress --authgroup=selectAuthGroup --user=UserName --passwd-on-stdin'
```

Comment: @MajidAlaeinia and for that `yes/no` question that is asking at first, you need tell me what is the question prompting you and so that I can add the relevant option to the commnad above to proceed that too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is the `yes/no` question: `Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view:`.

Comment: @MajidAlaeinia OK, that  is for server cert validation step I think; there should be a line before this prompt to say what is the server cert hash, you can take that and pass it to `--servercert=hashHere` to accept that too; depending on how authentication that server does, you may need to try different optoins too. `--no-cert-check`, `--no-system-trust` or from CA file `--cafile=FILE`. also you can answer anything else than `yes/no` to _view_ the cert and probably hash type of the cert  (I don't know much details)